# Querydsl: How to select specific column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using spring data jpa for creating services. Using `Querydsl` I am fetching records from multiple tables. I used mapping in model classes. `RoomDepartmentMapping` model class  is mapped with `department`, and `room`. and `room` is mapped with `building`.

I want to select only `building name` from `building`.

Can any one tell me How I can do?

**QueryDSL**

```
query.select(Projections.bean(RoomDepartmentMapping.class,roomDepartmentMapping.nRoomAllocationId,roomDepartmentMapping.sStatus,
        Projections.bean(Department.class,department.nDeptId,department.sClientDeptId,department.sDeptName).as("department"),
        Projections.bean(Room.class,room.nRoomId,room.sFloor,room.sRoomNumber,room.nBuildId,room.nCampusId,room.building).as("room")))           
             .from(roomDepartmentMapping);
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "nRoomAllocationId": 1,
    "sStatus": "A",
    "department": {
      "nDeptId": 21920,
      "sDeptName": "Unassignable Space",
      "sClientDeptId": "BBBBBB"
    },
    "room": {
      "nRoomId": 883886,
      "nCampusId": 231,
      "nBuildId": 9713,
      "sFloor": "9",
      "sRoomNumber": "914",
      "building": {
        "nBuildingId": 9713,
        "sBuildName": "Bronk Laboratory",
        "sClientBuildId": "406",
        "nBuildingInstId": 60,
        "nTempBuildingId": 2,
        "nNoOfFloors": 0
      },
      "nroomId": 883886
    }
  },
...
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

QueryDsl seems not to provide a way to customize fields which you want to display,
the choice is use jackson's @JsonProperty(serialized=false), it will hide the property which you don't want to display in the json string.